# How to force fargate service to be launched only from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I've created a simple task to print a hello world. I've created a ECR image, docker compose and ecs-params.yml.

I get the cloudwatch log for the print, but the task keeps launching every minute, which I guess it's due to REPLICA service type.

How can I stop this from happening, I want to launch this Fargate task ONLY from a lambda, and when it finishes I don't it to be relaunched.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a one-shot / one-off / standalone task to be launched by ECS and have it run until it finishes, you wouldn't use an ECS service definition but merely a task.
You can run tasks on their own without packaging as an ECS service.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task.html

If you are using the ECS CLI, then there is also [`ecs-cli compose create`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-create.html). So, you would use *that* call and *not* the one also creating an ECS service along with it.

You can then use AWS Lambda and send an [`ecs:RunTask`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) AWS API call to invoke/start the ECS task.

Comment: That can be it, yeah. But how can I generate the task from AWS CLI without creating the service along with it? To do it the first time i used `ecs-cli compose (...) service up`, so that it grabs docker-compose.yml + ecs-params.yml.

Comment: I've already created the task without any service inside the cluster, thank you! Now it's time to start the task from AWS Lambda